# Grouping low occuring levels in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a data frame that has a column called C. C has many levels that only occur once. How would I rename all of the levels that occur only once with a new level (called z)?

```
A  B  C   
a  a  a  
a  b  b  
a  a  c  
a  b  d  
a  b  a
```

The above would turn into:

```
A  B  C   
a  a  a  
a  b  z  
a  a  z  
a  b  z  
a  b  a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this (assuming your data is `df`)?

```
levels(df[,3])[table(df[,3])==1] <- "z"
df
  A B C
1 a a a
2 a b z
3 a a z
4 a b z
5 a b a
```

Comment: Another option would be `levels(x$C)[levels(x$C) != x$C[duplicated(x$C)]] = "z"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this but here is one solution:

```
df <- read.table(text = "A B C
                         a a a
                         a b b
                         a a c
                         a b d
                         a b a", header = TRUE)

# Get the number of times each factor occurs:
counts <- table(df$C)

# Replace each one that only occurs once with "z"
df$C <- ifelse(df$C %in% names(counts[counts == 1]), "z", as.character(df$C))

# Since the levels changed, encode as a factor again:
df$C <- factor(df$C)
```

This gives:

```
R> df$C
[1] a z z z a
Levels: a z
```

Answer (score 1):

using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(C) %>% 
       mutate(D = as.character(ifelse(n() == 1, "z", as.character(C))))
```

There is some ugly stuff to deal with the ifelse in there.